# MVC5 MasterName in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have simple Controller Action and knew how to pass model to rendered view but how to get  masterName in this view?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
var model =1;
 return View("Index","some master",model);
}
```

Comment: just set master name in viewbag and display on view `ViewBag.MasterName="some master" ;`, and here only `return view()`

Comment: you can put it like : return View("Index",model); no need to pass controller name here. if you want to set route value, you can set it from global asax

Comment: I knew about ViewBag and View() overloads but want how useful can be this kind of rendering

Comment: @Spam,*how useful can be this* in terms of what?

Comment: If is such View() method overloading it's mean that it can be use some how in View. So I now how to for what are  first ,and 3th parameter but have no idea hove can be used the second (masterName)

Comment: @Spam, Didn't get you, if something you didn't understand then update in the question.

Comment: What is masterName?  Are you trying to specify which `Layout` page or is `masterName` just some additional variable you want to pass?